# Examine an EXE to determine whether it is a user executable or a system service

Tags: winapi, service

Is there a way to examine an EXE file (PE header, etc.) to determine whether the file is a system service or a user executable?

I have an app suite that includes several system service modules, and more will likely be added in the future as we support more devices.  I want to be able to look at all the EXEs in a folder, determine which are services, and get their run state and version info to show the user, without having to "know" the specific filenames ahead of time.

Comment: Services as in ‘Windows services’? If so, then you can look in the registry to see whcih ex are actually registered as a service

Comment: Hi SteveS, you can check @Olaf's answer to see if it helps. Refer to [EnumServicesStatus](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winsvc/nf-winsvc-enumservicesstatusa).

Answer (score 1):

Enumerate through the list of services ([Windows API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10385783/how-to-get-a-list-of-all-services-on-windows-7) or registry [HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services]) and check whether their EXE path matches any of the files in the folder of interest to you.

Comment: The registry method was what I had thought about, but was curious if there was a way to do it by looking at the EXE itself - for the reason Dave noted below, I wasn't sure such a way was available, but if so, it would simplify things some.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible. It is perfectly possible, and even common, to build executable files that can be run as either a service or a standard process.

If you are in control of creating all the executable files then you could mark them yourself, for instance with a custom resource, to indicate what the intended use of the file is.

Comment: I suspected as much.  I am in control of all of the EXEs, but the scan-registry-and-compare method will do what I need without the need to modify and redistribute EXEs that are otherwise working fine at a bunch of sites.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

There's a heuristic, that will work most of the times, though may fail on either sides.

If a binary imports `StartServiceCtrlDispatcherA` or `StartServiceCtrlDispatcherW` it is likely to be able to work as a service, if not it is not likely.

It is not likely to delay import or `GetProcAddress` for this API. The most plausible caveat is that service binary could rely on another binary to call `StartServiceCtrlDispatcher`. As a particular case, it could be `svchost`-based.